# SQL & Java: Increment counter in a loop of result sets

Tags: java, sql

I need to know how I can make it so that variable *q* increment every time the while loop is completed.

```
int q;

try {
    System.out.println("given:");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Main.host, Main.uName, Main.uPass);

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    q = 1;
    String u = "SELECT *, COUNT(`like_user_id`) FROM `xf_liked_content` WHERE `xf_liked_content`.`like_user_id` = " + q;
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(u);

    while (rs.next()) {
        
        String count = rs.getString("COUNT(`like_user_id`)");
        String user_id = rs.getString("like_user_id");
        System.out.println(user_id + "|" + count);
        
        q++;
    }
} catch (SQLException err) {
    System.out.println(err.getMessage());
}
```

If there's a way to do this without an int, I'm open  for it.

---

### Edit by the author

This is a picture of the table:

[image: SQL table related to the question]

I need to get the count of times every `liked_user_id` is there.
By that I mean that if there's 4 rows with `like_user_id = 7`, the console output would be `7|4`.

> Expected outcome from the screenshot:
>
> 1|1
>
> 2|3

edit2: I've tried some other things by now, still no solution.

Comment: What is your problem right now? What isn't working?

Comment: Well, it only prints one result, like this:
1|1

Instead of my expectation:
1|1
...more like that

Comment: You modify `q` **after** you create and execute the query

Comment: How would I make it so that I can q to +1 unlimited?

Comment: the query is strange, if like_user_id = 99 what is the count supposed to be besides 1 (or no results)?

Comment: Assuming I'd have a like_user_id = 99 the count would have to be the amount of content that user has liked. example: user 99 has liked 6 different things, it would be 99|6

Comment: Right now you would need to create/modify the string `u` and execute the query again inside the `while` loop (after `q++;`), however that definitely looks like bad design (the queries will probably slow down the entire program) - you should try to change your query (and program logic) to not require providing the `like_user_id` in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: I editted my OP, hope I cleared up some things.

Comment: Uploaded the image to imgur, improved code formatting. A few minor changes to the text and its formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the SQL query (var `u`) to **select `like_user_id`, count(*) as count from `xf_liked_content` group by `like_user_id`**.

That worked, too.

Answer (score 0):

You have added a WHERE clause like_user_id = 1, which will likely return just 1 row. Some changes you can do :

1. Code conventions : select specific column names and use alias instead of count(*) as your column name
2. Remove the where clause to fetch a full list (or a better predictable where clause)

**Code** :

```
    try {

        System.out.println("given:");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Main.host, Main.uName, Main.uPass);

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String u = "SELECT `like_user_id`, COUNT(`like_user_id`) as count FROM `xf_liked_content`";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(u);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String count = rs.getString("count");
            String user_id = rs.getString("like_user_id");
            System.out.println(user_id + "|" + count);
        }
    }

    catch (SQLException err) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: @Chuchoter The suggestion of correcting the where clause was to address the same. You may have to try this once to see its results.

Comment: Hi, in the console it says "Column 'COUNT(`like_user_id`)' not found.".
Also, just executing it in SQL itself gives this: [link](https://gyazo.com/4bbae187a7f58fa085d047290e881c18).

Comment: Hi again, I've figured something else out, thanks for the help anyways! :)